# Display apps folder in dallery and images/video inside it like other popular apps

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android development and have been trying to accomplish the above said functionality.

I am testing app on Android 9, API 28. I am able to save captured image to folder but not been able to display it in gallery (Like WhatsApp).

I have tried:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    OutputStream os;
    String[] split = imagePathNew.split("\\.");
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, split[0] + ".jpg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "Test");
    Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    os = (OutputStream) resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri)); // imageLocalUri is the uri of captured image in folder
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, imageLocalUri);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    Objects.requireNonNull(os);
} else {
    Intent updateInGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    updateInGallery.setData(imageLocalUri); // imageLocalUri is the uri of captured image in folder
    context.sendBroadcast(updateInGallery);
}
```

Can someone please help me with what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the posted code.
In the addition use following class

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection#scanFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

From docs

> provides a way for applications to pass a newly created or downloaded media file to the media scanner service. The media scanner service will read metadata from the file and add the file to the media content provider.